# Put-Call parity arbitrage relationship

Tags: options, option-pricing, arbitrage, put-call-parity

I would like to know what the relationship is between the time value of call/puts. From the put call parity formula

$$C-P = S_{t} - PV(K)$$

and that value of call/put options is simply the sum of the intrinsic and time values 
$$C=(S-K)^++TV_C$$
$$P=(K-S)^++TV_P$$

Does that then imply that the no-arbitrage relationship is that the time value of $C$, $TV_C$, is equal to the time value of $P$, $TV_P$?

Comment: How are your time value defined? Note that, the conditional expectation is linear.

Comment: Yes, they are the same.  it is easier to see if you put your equation in terms of forward value.

Answer (score 3):

Into the first equation we can substitute $C$ and $P$ as given by the other two equations, we get:

$(S-K)^+ -(K-S)^+ +TV_C - TV_P = S-PV(K)$

$S-K+TV_C-TV_P=S-PV(K)$

$TV_C-TV_P=K-PV(K)$

If interest rates are zero then $PV(K)=K$ and then we indeed have

$TV_C=TV_P$

Note: as suggested in the comments above a slightly different definition of Intrinsic Value and Time Value might be preferable here. If we define the "modified time values" in the following way

$C=\underbrace{(S-PV(K))^+}_{IV^{'}_C}+TV^{'}_C$

$P=\underbrace{(PV(K)-S)^+}_{IV^{'}_P}+TV^{'}_P$

then we would have equality of the (modified) time values for any level of interest rates:

$TV^{'}_C=TV^{'}_P$